# Chaining of Java Optional map and orElse (if-else-style)

Tags: java, option-type

Is there an elegant and streaming way in Java to say "map this Optional to another Optional with a computed value if the value exists, else return an empty Optional"?

I thought of something like:

```
Optional<Float> amount = ...;
Optional<MonetaryAmount> myAmount = amount
    .map(theAmount -> FastMoney.of(theAmount, "EUR")).orElse(Optional.empty());
```

But this is not possible.

The solution I came up with is somewhat verbose and not streaming-like:

```
Optional<Float> amount = ...;
Optional<MonetaryAmount> myAmount = amount.isPresent() ?
          Optional.of(FastMoney.of(amount.get(), "EUR")) : Optional.empty();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `orElse` clause:

```
Optional<Float> amount = ...;
Optional<MonetaryAmount> myAmount =
    amount.map(theAmount -> FastMoney.of(theAmount, "EUR"));
```

Comment: Uuh, so simple. Thank you!